# Write into .log file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a script and every time something is done I would like to write into my custom .log file. How do I do that?

And in the end.. I'd just like to read it with Bash,.. do I just use cat?

Thanks.

Comment: sure, you can just use "echo" and/or redirect output using > and >> to a file.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question. Why the downvotes? If you downvote, please clarify. Even more if against a low-scored user that needs incentive, not downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `cat <log message here> >> custom.log`.

The `>>` means add on to the bottom of the file rather than `>` which would delete the contents of the file and then write the message.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest syntax I always use is `2>&1 | tee -a file_name.log`.

The syntax can be used after a command or execution of a file. e.g.

```
find . -type f 2>&1 | tee -a file_name.log
```

or

```
./test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a file_name.log
```